# Is it ok to use 301's this way?

Tags: 301-redirect

I installed a forum, which has a page for member info.  I want this to link to my main sites member info page which is a lot more detailed and interactive.

The forum membership page has the url:

member_profile.asp?PF=15434

If I put a 301 redirect on that page to go my nice member page:

Users/Tom

- Would search engines not index member_profile.asp?PF=15434 (as in I don't want that ugly URL appearing anywhere in results)
- Is it OK to use 301's this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that is fine to do if you cannot rewrite the forum code to display the more friendly URL to begin with. The 301 redirect will prevent the member_profile.asp?PF=15434 page from being indexed at all so only the "nice" member page will show in the search results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I CAN go through an change all the URL's, but it's a bit of a pain in the ass, is it worth doing?

Comment: Tom, this really is a question that you should ask yourself rather than others. Compare the time required for both solutions. Is the code modification so hard to perform? How much time will you spend managing all the 301 redirects? I guess if you can automate one solution, you can automate the other, too.